# Guard against killing an already killed process

Tags: kill

I'm writing a script that tries to kill a process. But the process might already been killed by others. How can I guard against it and prevent this kill command from terminating my process with throwing an error? I have `PID` of the process

Comment: How are you selecting the process you want to `kill`?

Comment: @JosephR. I have it in a variable inside my bash function

Comment: I meant are you killing the process by name or by PID?

Comment: @JosephR. PID __

Comment: Its logical to check the PID first if it exists then KILL it if it does.

Comment: If the PID does not exist because the process has already completed, the kill command will be completely harmless. Why do you even need to check this?

Comment: @jw013 I'm guessing this is to avoid failure when running with `-e`.

Comment: @JosephR. The right solution to that (completely different problem) is something along the lines of `kill pid || true`. When all you have is a PID, it is impossible to avoid race conditions if the state of the PID changes between when you check it and when you try to do something with it.

Comment: @Mohsen,  I'd be interested in seeing your script.  By default,  shell scripts will not terminate when a command fails.  If your script is failing, preventing it from failing when killing an already dead process should be a matter of just not making the script terminate on error.

Comment: @ctt It's a Jenkins job. They kill the job if they if a command exit with `0`

Comment: Your best bet, then would be to place your commands in a shell script which runs `kill` on the PIDs and then `exit 0`s unconditionally.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using pkill instead of kill. It will return 1 if no process matched. Test exit status of pkill to determine if it actually killed anything